# How to remove the class of an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to open a submenu, and that when selecting one of its options the submenu closes, for this I add and remove the class `show` as seen in the following code

```
$open.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  $submenu.classList.add("show");
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    $submenu.classList.remove("show");
  });
  $containertopics= document.getElementById("container_topics");
  $listtopics= document.getElementsByClassName("list__topics");
  loadsubmenu();
  for (let i of $listtopics) {
    i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      $submenu.classList.remove("show");
    });
  }
});
```

but the problem is that clicking on an item in the submenu does not remove the class, I have already tried to remove all its classes and add them one by one except the class see, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
$open.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loadsubmenu()
  $submenu.classList.toggle("show");
});

for (let i of $listtopics) {
  i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    $submenu.classList.remove("show");
  });
}

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target == $submenu) {
    $submenu.classList.remove("show");
  }
})
```

There was some problem with eventListeners as you are assigning a function every time '$open' is clicked.

Comment: There is another detail that I forgot to mention, and that is that the variables `containertopics` and `listtopics` are elements that only exist when I open the submenu, therefore the variables must be defined when the click event of the `$open` element occurs, and that is why I cannot separate the events just as you tell me

Comment: You can merge them but at least separate and replace the window eventListener. Your 'document.documentElement' cannot work as the menu is part of documentElement.

Comment: ok, I will try other solutions and upload the solution when I find it.
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your HTML code here to know to us what is the error generate from your code. So I have created a example for you. Get the Idea. You can use `.removeClass` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="highlight">Remove class from the element</p>
    <button type="button">Remove Class</button>
```

[here is the JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/smx9ebqk/32/)

Comment: I am trying not to use jquery, but if I have no more options I would use it